# You will need a new app to open this windows defender link

Tags: windows-defender, windows-11-upgrade

I have recently upgraded to `Windows 11` which is now on the `Beta Channel`, the only unofficial problem I have is with `Windows Security`.

Here's What I get when I try to click on any Windows Security link

[image: Here's What I get when I try to click on any Windows Security link]

I tried all solutions on the official docs, articles, etc.., but nothing worked for me.

**Note:** commands like `Get-AppxPackage` to get a manual installation gave me an error when trying to execute them.

**Version:**

`Windows 11 Pro Version 21H2 build 22000.132`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here's What I get when I try to click on any Windows Security link
>
> [image]

The following command will fix Windows Defender:

> `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage`

There honestly wasn't anything special about the command I suggested.  The problem described can happen on Windows 10.  On Windows 10 it appears the package was instead called `Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI`.  Performing a Reset on a UWP application is a normal operation, it's only more complicated, due to the fact `Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI` or `Microsoft.SecHealthUI` isn't your typical UWP package.

The "You'll need ..." message can happen with any file extension and performing a Reset on the appropriate UWP package will typically solve the problem.

Source: [Windows 11 Security-Center not Working after Update from Windows 10](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-insider-program/windows-11-security-center-not-working-after-update-from-windows/m-p/2619752)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Windows 11 (offered through Windows Update, on PC not joined in the Windows Insider Program), it wasn't possible to open Windows Security under one of the user accounts and resetting it with command from the accepted answer didn't help.

By running this in PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name "Microsoft.SecHealthUI" -User $env:UserName
```

I found out that the `Microsoft.SecHealthUI` package wasn't registered for this user - it resulted in an empty output. After that I ran this command, but replacing `$env:UserName` with a user name for which the Windows Security wasn't broken.

The output included the package install location folder:

```
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SecHealthUI_1000.22000.1.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

*Note that the exact name of this folder could change if its version number changes (perhaps after a new Windows 11 build is released).*

**Now it was possible to run this to repair the Windows Security for that user:**

```
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SecHealthUI_1000.22000.1.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppXManifest.xml"
```