# Windows Defender service won't start (Access Denied)

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall, windows-defender

I wanted to install XBOX app but whenever I install it I got the error

> looks like something went wrong 0x80073D0A

I looked this code and it seems it wants Windows Defender to be on, so I went to check Windows defender but I can't open it, whenever I click it the open with window popup telling me

> you'll need a new app to open this windowsdefender link

[image: windowsdefender link]
then I tried to check the services for the Windows defender advanced and firewall services but found them set to manual and disabled respectively, whenever I try to start it I get this error
[image: Window Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service started and then stopped]

whenever I try to switch it to automatic, it tells me Access Denied though I opened services as Administrator and I'm using an Administrator account.
[image: Access Denied]

while for the Windows Defender Firewall everything is grayed out, I can't start, stop, restart or change its mode in the properties.

I tried to turn on the firewall from the control panel but I got this error  ox80070422
[image: ox80070422]

later I installed and ran Malwarebytes but didn't find any threats/detections.
I'm using a personal computer not a business or an office one, so any suggestions on how to exit this problem ?

my specifications are Windows 10 pro with 20H2 build.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1670249/you-will-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-windowsdefender-link/1670370#1670370) should solve the issue. At least the Windows Defender part of it, rest of your issue, can be solved by an in-place repair

Comment: I couldn't run the command on the windows shell, it tells me :

Comment: `Reset-AppxPackage : The term 'Reset-AppxPackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:51
+ Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Reset-AppxPackage:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: It’s a PowerShell command….

Comment: yes I know I've tried it with PowerShell and this error came , https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ad0u.png

Comment: My apologies Reset-AppxPackage is only a feature of Windows 11. The only other way I know to solve the problem was an in-place repair

Comment: no problem but what do you mean by in-place repair ?

Comment: I mean run the Windows installer from within Windows, if your not an Administrator, that won’t be option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read that a lot of people reported that the in-place repair might cause failure of the windows that I might need to install a totally new one after it so I kept it as the last solution.

to sum up and close what I did to solve this problem :

for the problem of "a new app is required to open this windowsdefender link", I used the solution proposed by this link https://www.minitool.com/news/you-need-new-app-to-open-windowsdefender.html

for the problem of the firewall "windows defender can't change some of your settings error code 0x80070422, I've used the solution proposed here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-defender-firewall-services-are-greyed-out/66aa9517-16cd-41f8-a30f-dde314561651

as for the problems of the windows defender advanced threat protection showing "access denied" and not starting, I've just ignored it as xbox app, which made me start discovering this mess, finally allowed its installation, so now I don't really need the "stupid" windows defender security as I've mentioned that I've Malwarebytes and it works just fine.

I'll keep the in-place upgrade solution for later now as there's no reason to risk anything.