# Dell touchpad not scrolling

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, dell-latitude

**EDIT**:

**Under PS 7.1.3**,

```
> Get-AppxPackage alpsdelltouchpadsettings
Get-AppxPackage: The 'Get-AppxPackage' command was found in the module 'Appx', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Appx'
```

Following that, I tried what was instructed, and

```
> Import-Module Appx
Import-Module: Operation is not supported on this platform. (0x80131539)
```

which is widely reported in the web.
So I stopped trying with PS 7.1.3.

**Under PS 5.1**,

```
> Get-AppxPackage alpsdelltouchpadsettings
```

returns nothing, but it works.
So I tried finding the package by trial and error:

```
> Get-AppxPackage | grep alp
> Get-AppxPackage | grep touch
> Get-AppxPackage | grep input
```

None of these found any results.
(I am a newbie with PS, but at one point I made sure `grep` and other commands were aliased, and I just double checked with `Get-AppxPackage | grep power` that `grep` is working, and it is case-insensitive).

---

My Dell Latitude touchpad is not scrolling with two fingers.
I tried going to the *Control Panel* -> *Dell Touchpad*, but it doesn't work.

[image]

And I don't see any setting for the touchpad in *Control Panel* -> *Mouse*.
This is the closest I get

[image]

**Related**:

1. https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/you-ll-a-new-app-to-open-this-alpsdelltouchpadsettings/td-p/6228473

Comment: The simplest solution to this problem is to uninstall and reinstall `alpsdelltouchpadsettings` from the Microsoft Store.  The ["You'll need a new app to open this ..."](https://superuser.com/questions/1670249/you-will-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-windowsdefender-link/1670370#1670370) message indicates an application configuration issue and isn't unique to the application in question.

Comment: I would try simply running `wsreset.exe` as an Administrator.  Sadly the cmdlet you need to solve this problem (Reset-AppxPackage), or at least the way I know will solve the problem, requires Windows 11. There should be an entry for the application within `Apps > Apps & features` with a Reset button I would try that also.  [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/dell-touchpad-assistant/9n5gllfvs68r?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) is the application you need to reinstall

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest requires more information.  `Get-AppxPackage alpsdelltouchpadsettings` should provide that information.

Comment: What about *Settings - Devices - Touchpad*.

Comment: @user1644677 - It shows everything normal, but still gestures/scrolling do not work.

Comment: You have been around long enough to know that information like that should be in your question instead of a comment.  If alpsdelltouchpadsettings isn’t the correct package you will have to tell us what the correct package name is, I have a solution to your problem, but the correct package name must be provided.

Comment: Appears to be localized name as specified in your screenshot as *launchalpsdelltouchpadsettings*, since I don’t feel like helping with PowerShell environment issues, use PS 5.1

Comment: @Ramhound - Right, fixed. As for the correct package, I have currently no idea how to get that name. 
I tried a few things under PS5.1, see EDITed OP, but with no results.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio - Do you even have the Dell Touchpad Settings application from the Windows Store installed? You could try something like `Get-AppxPackage *Dell` but unless you can provide a package name I can't provide the command to fix installation of said package.

Comment: @Ramhound - I don't know what happened, but now it is working. I don't even have a candidate action that I might have taken as an attempt to fix things.