# Windows 11 Security alert - but no results for Windows Defender in the Windows appstore

Tags: security, windows-11, windows-defender

I've upgraded to Windows 11. Now I see this alert in the taskbar:

[image: Windows 11 security alert]

In Windows 10 I would doubleclick this icon and the security center opens. Nothing happens now. Rightclicking gives some options, like check for security updates. When I choose that, I see this message: You need a new app to open this windowsdefender-link.

[image: You need a new app to open this Windowsdefender link]

Strange! Why isn't there a default app installed? So I click it and the Windows appstore opens. Guess what: Results for windowsdefender: no results found!

[image: Results for windowsdefender: no results found]

How can I get Defender working?

NB: This problem persisted after applying all updates.

Comment: Windows Defender need attention - open it and see what is going on.

Comment: You also have windows updates to do.  Update and likely WD will update as well.

Comment: "Is this some new Microsoft logic?" - No; "Is there a new antivirus app for W11?" - No; It's still Windows Defender. "Why doesn't this work out of the box?" - I cannot read German so I will be unable to respond to the behavior itself.  However, I suspect, it's the same message as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1670249/you-will-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-windows-defender-link/1670370#1670370) question.  You will have to tell me since I am extremely lazy, and don't feel like trying to translate German into English.  You should take the time to provide that English translation.

Comment: @Ramhound, that link solved the problem.