# I can't disable tamper protection because windows defender is missing

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

so to explain my problem : I have a version of windows with windows defender completely removed, if I try to access it through windows settings it just says "you need a new app to open the windowsdefender link"

I always thought that all windows defender features were disabled, the WD service doesn't exist and I never saw any active process about it.. But one particular program I'm trying to use needs tamper protection disabled and it detected it as still enabled.

I tried to disable tamper protection in registry , but it didnt change anything
I also tried to re-install windows defender to turn off tamper protection before disabling WD gain, but i didn't succeed either

Does anyone have an idea for a solution that doesn't include having to format and install a new windows?

Thanks

Comment: I would be very suspicious of a program that requires tamper protection to be disabled...

Comment: You will be best to back up your data and reinstall Windows

Comment: [Windows Defender likely isn’t actually missing.  There is an explanation for the behavior, but the only solution I can suggest, only works for Windows 11. How did you come to install a modified version of Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1670249/you-will-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-windows-defender-link/1670370#1670370). I assume the message in my answer is the message you are receiving?

Comment: Yes same message , I tried to add WD back with these powershell commands for w10 , didnt worked for me
Looks like my only option is reinstall windows completely :(

Comment: I had this issue on a Windows 11 Insider machine and had to do a vigorous Repair Install to fix it. Power Shell did not work in this situation. Back up and reinstall.